# How to change component color on button click

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

im trying to make a painting game in javascript but can't seem to change the color of the 'PaintBrush' component. I want to do it via a function and have a button do that function onclick. I have it all sorted out except how to get the paint brush to change color. This is quite complex so please help. Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<html>
<body onload="startGame()">
<br>
<button onclick="ThickRed()">Thick Red</button>
<button onclick="ThinRed()">Thin Red</button>
<button onclick="ThickYellow()">Thick Yellow</button>
<button onclick="ThinYellow()">Thin Yellow</button>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
canvas {
border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function startGame() {
GameArena.start();
}
var PaintBrush; 
var GameArena = {
canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
start : function() {
    this.canvas.width = 1280;
    this.canvas.height = 480;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
  this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
},
clear : function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
}
}
function startGame() {
GameArena.start();
PaintBrush = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 320);
}
function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
this.speedX = 0;
this.speedY = 0;
this.x = x;
this.y = y; 
this.color = color;
this.update = function(){
ctx = GameArena.context;
ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
this.newPos = function() {
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY; 
} 

}
function updateGameArea() {
PaintBrush.newPos();
PaintBrush.update();
}
function checkKey(e) {

if (e.keyCode == '38') {
    // up arrow
   PaintBrush.speedY -= 1;
}
else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
    // down arrow
  PaintBrush.speedY += 1;
}
else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
   // left arrow
  PaintBrush.speedX -= 1;
}
else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
   // right arrow
  PaintBrush.speedX += 1;
}

}
function ThickYellow() {
PaintBrush.color = Yellow;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Two things, what is Yellow? try "yellow", after you update the brushes color, make sure ctx.fillStyle is using the right color.  You want this.color, not color.  The way that you have it currently, your paintbrush will always render with the initial color that was specified on creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use string `"yellow"` instead of `Yellow` or define `var Yellow = "yellow"`at the top of your file.
To reflect the `context.fillStyle` with selected color modify your `update` function as below. The difference is `ctx.fillStyle = this.color` not just `color`.

```
this.update = function () {
            ctx = GameArena.context;
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to organize the code in the bit object oriented way here follows your code.

You can also find the running example in JSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rj1405/qa7q0b9m/

For simplicity, I have a button to start the game (you can replace with on document load) and 2 buttons, Red and Yellow.

```
<button id="btn">StartGame</button>
<button id="btnRed" >Thick Red</button>
<button id="btnYellow">Thick Yellow</button>
```

Your CSS,

```
canvas { border: 1px solid #d3d3d3; background-color: #f1f1f1; }
```

Here is the main javascript.

document.onkeydown = checkKey;

```
// Global variables
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var btnYellow = document.getElementById('btnYellow');
var btnRed = document.getElementById('btnRed');
var paintBrush;

// Main GameArena object
var GameArena = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
            this.canvas.width = 1280;
            this.canvas.height = 480;
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
         document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas,document.body.childNodes[0]);
            this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
   clear : function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);
    }
 };

// Paint Brush Constructor
var PaintBrush = function (width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;

    this.update = function(){
        ctx = GameArena.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };

   this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY; 
    };
 }

 PaintBrush.prototype.setColor = function(color){
     this.color = color;
     this.update();
 };  


// On click Button events
 btn.onclick = function(e) {
    GameArena.start();
    paintBrush = new PaintBrush(30, 30, "red", 10, 320);
 };

 btnYellow.onclick = function(e) {
    paintBrush.setColor('yellow');
 };

 btnRed.onclick = function(e) {
    paintBrush.setColor('red');
 };

 // Other methods
 function updateGameArea() {
    paintBrush.newPos();
    paintBrush.update();
 }

 function checkKey(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == '38') {
       paintBrush.speedY -= 1;
     }
     else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
       paintBrush.speedY += 1;
     }
     else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
       paintBrush.speedX -= 1;
     }
     else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
       paintBrush.speedX += 1;
     }
 }
```

Please note, I have used global variables. This code resolves your quession, but it can be improvised in many ways.

Comment: Thanks for organising my code, although in my code i only had to have ctx.fillStyle = this.color and have the colors become "yellow" instead of Yellow